# Where do I put a servlet jar file in Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, classpath, tomcat6

I have a servlet in a jar file which I want to deploy to my Tomcat 6 instance.  I did the following things:

1. added a servlet declaration in my root web.xml
2. added a servlet-mapping in the root web.xml
3. put my jar file in /tomcat/lib
4. re-started my server

I am getting the following error when I direct to my servlet

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class com.mypackage.myServlet or a class it depends on
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mypackage.myServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This says to me that my web.xml is configured correctly and I am successfully hitting the right URL pattern.  So the question is... where do I put a servlet jar file in Tomcat 6 so it gets picked up in the CLASSPATH?

TIA

Comment: @Bozho, anything positive to add to the discussion?  Where did your answer go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not the normal practice, it should work fine. Because it should in theory work, I've tested it locally and it works fine (Tomcat 6.0.20 and 7.0.5). You've probably a typo in the `<servlet-class>`. The classname of your servlet namely starts with a lowercase, which goes totally against the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Try

```
<servlet-class>com.mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
```

instead.

If that doesn't fix it, then unpack the JAR with some ZIP/RAR tool and verify if the `com/mypackage/MyServlet.class` file is present.

If the file is actually present, then you're probably using some IDE which has only a specific subset of the jars of `Tomcat/lib` in a copy of Tomcat which is controlled/managed by the IDE. Try deploy and run Tomcat standalone the hard way in command console.

Comment: thanks, I'll go check again.  I have protected the real package names for purposes of anonymity, but I could easily have made a typo.

Comment: This led me to the right place.  This works as described, you can put a servlet jar in the lib folder and configure the root web.xml to direct to it.  The issue I had was not about spelling, it was about caching on the server.  I did a hard clean of all cached resources and started up and my configuration worked fine.  My IDE (Eclipse Helios) wasn't really cleaning completely, I had to do it myself (work directories under the tomcat folder).  Works fine now.

Comment: @Simon How to configure the root web.xml to direct it.
My servlet classes are inside jar files which is kept inside war lib folder.
<servlet>
  <description>
  </description>
  <display-name>
  ServletName</display-name>
  <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
  com.servlet.ServletName</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <description>
   </description>
   <param-name>InitFileName</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/Servlet.ini</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

Comment: I am receiving File not found exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your servlet JAR files goes in the WAR's `lib` directory, not in the top-level Tomcat `lib` directory, i.e.

```
<war-root>
   /WEB-INF
      web.xml
   /lib
      myservlet.jar
```

Comment: so I cannot deploy a servlet as a jar file?  How does the default jsp servlet work?  why can't I do the same?